# Can't write string in exception constructor

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008

Visual Studio seems to complain when I pass a string into an exception parameter.

```
if (str1 == null || str2 == null)
{
    throw new ArgumentNullException("lmkl");
}
```

Visual Studio says that it cannot resolve symbol `"lmkl"`.

If I have a string variable (eg above `throw new... string s = "test";`) and include this as the parameter for the exception, Visual Studio is more than happy with this.

What gives?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the ArgNullEx from the BCL or implementing your own?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The documentation for the overloaded constructor for `ArgumentNullException` that takes a single string parameter states that this argument should be:

```
The name of the parameter that caused the exception.
```

At the moment, if your code throws an exception you won't know which argument was null.

Recommend rewriting to

```
if (str1 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("str1");
if (str2 == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("str2");
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually, Visual Studio doesn't care about this **at all**. I assume you have [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) installed? This validates a lot of common errors, including incorrect use of patterns such as `ArgumentException` etc. It also has better `null` checking - not quite "contracts", but still pretty helpful.

It only attempts this when it can see a string literal used in a known pattern - the analysis to chase how you assign variables is simply too much for realistic analysis.

Comment: Yep I use resharper. Haven't seen it do its stuff with exceptions in my code, other than that it's been a good tool to work with. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ReSharper, this should suppress the warning (assuming str1 is the name of your param):

```
throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(str1));
```